# How to handle System.ArgumentNullException?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, null, arguments

When I am debugging the below code block, I am getting System.ArgumentNullException .

```
public string StartDeviceDiagnosis(DiagnosticsOption diagnosticsOption)
        {
            var aggregator = ServiceProviderHandle.ServiceProvider.GetService<**IAggregator**>();
            this.CreateDeviceStatusReport(DiagnosticConstant.DeviceStatusReportHTMLFileName);
            return aggregator.AggregateLogs(diagnosticsOption, true);
        }
```

System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: provider'

I tried adding try-catch block to handle the exception, but I wasn't able to do that as the method has to return a string.

Comment: `ServiceProviderHandle.ServiceProvider` is `null` - you need to work out why that is, and resolve it.

Comment: I've linked your question to one which provides some helpful tips on debugging NullReferenceExceptions.